# Showing $x^3$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

Referring to the original source http://math.stanford.edu/~ksound/Math171S10/Hw8Sol_171.pdf

> Prove that $f(x) = x^3$ is not uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$.

I want to use a more elementary method, no mention of metric spaces. Their selection of $\delta$ confuses me, so I am want to present a more "elementary" method. I am unsure if it is correct.

Here I picked $|a| > \dfrac{\epsilon}{3\delta}$ and $x > a - \delta$

Thus $$\begin{align}
|x^3 - a^3| &= |x - a||x^2 + ax + a^2| \\&>|x^2+ax +a^2| \\&> |(a-\delta)^2+a(a - \delta) + a^2|\\&=|3a^2-3a\delta+\delta^2| \\&> 3\delta|a|
\end{align}$$

Comment: $|x - a||x^2 + ax + a^2| >|x^2+ax +a^2|$ need not hold without additional assumptions.

Comment: Why does the use of $d(x, y)$ confuse you?   It's just shorthand for $|x - y|$.

Comment: @Ink: $d(x,y)$ is generalization of distance function, not necessarily same as $|x-y|$

Comment: @Avatar In this case, it's just $|x - y|$.

Comment: @Ink: i agree with that.

Comment: @vadim123, aren't I just look at $|x||y| > |y|$ ?Oh wait, $|x - a|$ could be $<1$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Their solution doesn't really use any ideas from metric spaces.  Here is an elaboration.

Suppose $f(x)=x^3$ were uniformly continuous.  Then for any $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta$ that works for all $a$.  Let's take $\epsilon=1$; we are now given $\delta$ such that for all $a$ and for all $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta$, we must have $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

Choose $a$ large enough so that $\frac{3\delta a^2}{2}>1$; for example $a=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3\delta}}+1$ works. Now take $x=a+\frac{\delta}{2}$; this satisfies $|x-a|=\frac{\delta}{2}<\delta$.  Hence we SHOULD have $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon=1$.  Instead we have $|f(x)-f(a)|=|f(a+\frac{\delta}{2})-f(a)|=|(a+\frac{\delta}{2})^3-a^3|=\left|3a^2\frac{\delta}{2}+3a\frac{\delta^2}{4}+\frac{\delta^3}{8}\right|\ge \left|3a^2\frac{\delta}{2}\right|>1$.

This is a contradiction, and hence $f(x)$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: How did you get *so that $\frac{3\delta a^2}{2} > 1$* in the first place?

Comment: $\delta$ is supposed to work for all $a$, so we can pick $a$ as large as we want.  The REASON I want $\frac{3\delta a^2}{2}>1$ is to make the contradiction work out in the end.

Comment: Ok, but how did you pick that out in the first place; the same for $x = a + \delta/2$

Comment: The way *I* picked them out is by following the proof in the link you provided.  The way *they* picked them out is by working out the algebra beforehand and keeping the values that work.

Comment: Can you show me the algebra they worked out beforehand? That's the part I have trouble.

Comment: In particular, how/why you chose $\delta/2$

Comment: $\frac{\delta}{2}$ is just a convenient number that is between $0$ and $\delta$.  It is the first one that comes to mind, for me at least.

Answer (score 10):

Recall that the definition of uniform continuity is

> $f:A\to\Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous iff for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ (depending solely on $\epsilon$) such that whenever $x,y\in A$ and $|x-y|<\delta$; it follows $$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$

Now, in order to prove a function is **not uniformly** continuous, we ought to show that

> There exists $\epsilon >0$ such that for any $\delta >0$ we can find $x,y\in A$ for which $|x-y|<\delta$ yet $$|f(x)-f(y)|\geq \epsilon$$

This translates almost immediately to

> There exist a pair of sequences $\langle x_n\rangle ,\langle y_n\rangle$ in $A$ such that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(x_n-y_n)=0$$ yet $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(f(x_n)-f(y_n))\neq 0$$

Now, can you find such sequences for $f(x)=x^3$?

**HINT** Think about $x_n=(n+1)^{1/3}$, $y_n=n^{1/3}$. It shouldn't be surprising the sequences are unbounded, and yet become arbitrarily close. In fact, $x^3$ **is** uniformly continuous on any bounded interval, so it is necessary the sequences are unbounded. This is in essence why uniform continuity fails here. Note the functional inverse $x^{1/3}$ **is** uniformly continuous over $\Bbb R$.

**OBS** The above can be used to show $x^n$ is not uniformly continuous whenever $n> 1$.

Comment: Student question, but how did you *this translates almost immediately to*?

Comment: @sidht Look at $\delta=1,\frac 12,\frac 13,\ldots,\frac 1n,\ldots$. Since $x,y$ depend on $\delta$ (I should have written $x_\delta,y_\delta$ to be fair) we find a sequence of points $x_n,y_n$ such that $|x_n-y_n|<\frac 1 n $ but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\geq \epsilon$

Comment: Oh wait does it have to do with $|z_n| < \delta$, but $|f(z_n)| \geq \epsilon$?

Comment: @sidht Yes, I edited my comment.

Comment: So basically (sorry for dumbing this down even further) we are imitating the definition for continuity (regular continuity) in some sort?

Comment: @sidht: Uniform continuity is a very special sort of continuity. With regular continuity: *given a point* $a$ in the domain of a continuous function $f$, we can keep $f(x)$ as close to $f(a)$ as we like, simply by keeping $x$ close enough to $a$. With uniform continuity: we can keep $f(x)$ as close to $f(a)$ as we like for ***any*** $a$ in the domain of a uniformly continuous function $f$, just by keeping $x$ close enough to $a$. For continuity, "close enough" will depend in general on our $a$ **and** our "close as we like". For *uniform* continuity, it depends only on our "close as we like".