# Determine whether the following are uniformly continuous

Tags: general-topology, uniform-continuity

Determine whether the following are uniformly continuous

(a) $ x \rightarrow x^3, x\in \mathbb{R} $ and (b) $ x \rightarrow x^3, x\in [0,1] $.

I just don't get these, I figured that (b) is and (a) isn't but I have no idea how to prove them.

Comment: A continuous function from a closed and bounded interval into $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous. For a) see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428528/showing-x3-is-not-uniformly-continuous-on-mathbbr

Comment: @R.vW: Could you please say what you don't get? Do you understand intuitively the difference between continuity and uniform continuity? Do you know of geometric criteria for uniform continuity, e.g., "for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that the image of an arbitrary interval of length $\delta$ has length at most $\varepsilon$"?

Comment: @Demophilus (+1) good link.

Comment: I do get the difference but I don't get the right way of proving this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a) $, consider

$$u_n=n$$
and
$$v_n=n+\frac 1 n$$
we have

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(v_n-u_n)=0$$
but
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(v_n^3-u_n^3)=+\infty\ne 0$$

thus $x \mapsto x^3$ is not uniformly continuous at $\mathbb R $.

> for $b) $

$$x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2) $$
with
$0\le x\le1$ and $0\le y\le 1$, thus
$$|x^3-y^3|\le 3|x-y|$$

then to satisfy $|x^3-y^3|<\epsilon $, take $\eta=\frac {\epsilon}{3} $.

Comment: And what how would one do 1 without the use of Heine's theorem (I haven't had and I won't learn that theorem).